# How to I /setblock repeaters facing different directions?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to know how I can use `/setblock` to spawn repeaters facing different directions. Like if I wanted to have a repeater facing east what command do I write?

Comment: http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Data_values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set a block to repeater via this command:

```
/setblock ~ ~ ~ minecraft:unpowered_repeater
```

That places a repeater facing north, with a one tick delay. If you want to create a different repeater you have to calculate a datavalue, with this formula:

> datavalue = direction + (4 * delay)

Where the delay goes from 0 to 3, and the direction goes like this:

- 0: North
- 1: East
- 2: South
- 3: West

For example, if you want to create a repeater facing east with the least amount of delay you calculate:

> datavalue = 1 + (4 * 0) = 1

To then create that repeater execute this command:

```
/setblock ~ ~ ~ minecraft:unpowered_repeater 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Minecraft 1.13 and newer versions no longer rely on cryptic numbers to encode things like facing, meaning that you can just do `/setblock x y z repeater[facing=east]`