# Is there a way to change the way chests are facing in /summon?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am creating an adventure map and players will need items every so often so I am using

```
/summon FallingSand 2140.5 9 -423.5 {TileID:54,Time:1,TileEntityData:{Items:[{id:diamond_helmet,Slot:0,Count:1},{id:diamond_chestplate,Slot:1,Count:1},{id:diamond_leggings,Slot:2,Count:1},{id:diamond_boots,Slot:3,Count:1},{id:diamond_sword,Slot:4,Count:1}]}}
```

To summon a chest with the items in it. When the chest spawns it auto-faces South, is there a way using datatags to make it face North?

Comment: Why are you summoning a falling sand entity instead of using `setblock`?  As a bonus, using `setblock` will solve your problem.

Comment: @MBraedley Can you please answer the question with a command using /setblock that will fix my error?

Comment: It's going to be hard for me to provide a meaningful answer if you don't answer my question first.  There's good reasons why you might use falling sand instead of `setblock`.  As it turns out, you are able to do what you want with falling sand, but the more important point is that you seem to be stuck in the [X/Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  You're assuming the solution, at least with your title, instead of focusing on the problem.

Comment: @DavidCole this might be useful http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/191936/how-to-i-setblock-repeaters-facing-different-directions

Comment: As a side-note, `TileID` is kind of deprecated in 1.8, the `Block` tag should be used instead.

Answer (score 1):

The facing of a chest is determined by it's [block data value](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Chest#Block_data), ranging from 2 to 5 (North, South, West, East). For [Falling Sand Entities](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Chunk_format#Dynamic_tiles) the data value of the block can be set by adding a `Data` tag to the entity:

```
/summon FallingSand 2140.5 9 -423.5 {Block:minecraft:chest,Data:2,Time:1,TileEntityData:{Items:[{id:diamond_helmet,Slot:0,Count:1},{id:diamond_chestplate,Slot:1,Count:1},{id:diamond_leggings,Slot:2,Count:1},{id:diamond_boots,Slot:3,Count:1},{id:diamond_sword,Slot:4,Count:1}]}}
```

(I also replaced `TileID` with the newer `Block`. This doesn't exactly matter, but numerical IDs are being phased out gradually, and I expect `TileID` to break in the future.)

---

However, as pointed out by [MBraedley](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/1351/mbraedley) in the comments, summoning a chest with items can be done directly via [`setblock`](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#setblock), rather than using the old roundabout way of summoning falling sand.

The syntax is

```
/setblock <x> <y> <z> <TileName> [dataValue] [oldBlockHandling] [dataTag]
```

Here, the data value can be set directly. To set the data tag, you'll need to specify `oldBlockHandling`, I suggest using the default value of `replace`:

```
/setblock 2140 9 -423 minecraft:chest 2 replace {Items:[{id:diamond_helmet,Slot:0,Count:1},{id:diamond_chestplate,Slot:1,Count:1},{id:diamond_leggings,Slot:2,Count:1},{id:diamond_boots,Slot:3,Count:1},{id:diamond_sword,Slot:4,Count:1}]}
```

This command is not only shorter and easier to read, it also executes much faster than the summon version. That is because it doesn't need to create an entity, have it drop to the floor, determine collision, and then turn it into a block and remove the entity.